# How to get latest spotify update

Tags: upgrade, spotify

According to the some news outlets, we have a Spotify update (as well as the one for Windows and MacOS) related to the app itself writing tons of data to the drive:

- https://9to5mac.com/2016/11/11/spotify-bug-data-fix/
- http://www.pcmag.com/news/349525/report-spotify-fixes-hard-drive-killing-desktop-glitch
- http://www.zdnet.com/article/spotify-windows-mac-linux-desktop-app-update-now-to-stop-it-trashing-your-ssd/
- http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-37950627
- https://www.neowin.net/news/spotify-patches-its-app-after-writing-gigabytes-of-junk-data-onto-storage-drives

I tried upgrading the app itself using `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade Spotify` or `sudo apt-get upgrade Spotify` but it keeps saying `unable to locate package Spotify`.

I am assuming that reinstalling the app will give me the most recent or updated version but I cannot verify that yet.

What is the correct syntax to update Spotify in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the **terminal** application. Copy and paste the following commands.

1. Add the Spotify repository signing key to be able to verify downloaded packages

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys BBEBDCB318AD50EC6865090613B00F1FD2C19886
   ```
2. Add the Spotify repository

   ```
   echo deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
   ```
3. Update list of available packages

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Install Spotify

   ```
   sudo apt-get install spotify-client
   ```

**Source**: information taken from https://www.spotify.com/us/download/linux/

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed Spotify's snap package, you can easily refresh

```
snap refresh spotify
```